# Origin of Singapore Cantonese /œː/ being realised as [jɔ]

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics, cantonese

I've recently been taking Cantonese lessons from a Hong Kong native speaker, and as a result I realised that the Cantonese speakers in my family (who are also native speakers, but from Singapore) all pronounce the phoneme /œː/ something like [jɔ]. Does this realisation originate somewhere in China, or is it something that arose in Singapore?

Examples are the word 兩 (loeng5), which I've always heard pronounced roughly like [ljɔŋ]. And the phrase 緊張 (gan2 zoeng1), which has entered general (non-Chinese) Singlish usage, is pronounced [kan t͡ɕjɔŋ]. (This might be a bad example because 緊張 might be borrowed into Singlish from Hokkien and not Cantonese, I'm not sure.) I don't think it's just before [ŋ] as well; to test this I asked my mother how to say "bird" in Cantonese and she said [t͡ɕjɔk] whereas my teacher says [tsœːk] for 雀 (zoek3).

I hope this isn't a dumb question but I couldn't find much online even referring to this sound change as a feature of Singaporean Cantonese, let alone what its source might be, and whether it is perhaps a Hokkien influence that happened in Singapore, or perhaps a vestige of a dialect of Cantonese spoken in China. Thanks!

Comment: While I don’t know much about Cantonese (you’ll probably want @Michaelyus for that), I can say that out of your three examples, two correspond to Mandarin syllables that have a palatal glide ([j] in 兩 _liǎng_, [ɥ] in 雀 _què_), and the third is reconstructed to have had one in Middle Chinese (張 /trjaŋ/, /ʈiɐŋ/, /ȶi̯aŋ/, etc., depending on whose reconstructions you follow). So it would not be unexpected at all if some forms of Cantonese retained /jɔ/ sequences, while others (Hong Kong) merged them into /œ/ through [_i_-mutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-mutation).

Comment: That basically is the answer @JanusBahsJacquet!

Comment: @Michaelyus Ah, so the [jɔ] pronunciation is (in some sense) the older pronunciation and not a Hokkien-influenced mangling of [œ]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

香, 兩, 想 all belong to the 陽 final in Middle Chinese, which is reconstructed as having (Baxter) *jang* / (Wang Li) /ĭaŋ/.

This final regularly became /œːŋ/ in the 廣府 Guangfu region, as we hear across the Pearl River Delta. This passed [through a rounding stage first](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110822014.185/html?lang=en) (as with the majority of Middle Chinese instances of /aŋ/ in Cantonese), with /ĭaŋ~jaŋ/ resulting in */jɔŋ/. This underwent some i-mutation, but this is gradual and fairly recent; even by 1856 when Samuel Wells compiles [*A tonic dictionary of the Chinese language in the Canton dialect*](https://archive.org/details/atonicdictionar00willgoog/page/n25/mode/1up) (page xxii), the final still includes the glide:

> *éu* as in *Capernaum, say 'em* ; *héung, léuk*

Note that in other Yue varieties such as Hoisanese/Toisanese/Taishanese (台山話), the 陽 final is *still* realised with a glide, and sometimes the vowel retains a more conservative variant, such as /jaŋ/ [in 台城/赤坎] or /jɔŋ/ [in 牛江] or /jœŋ/ [in 白沙].

However, it is not likely that Straits Cantonese draws a direct line of descent from these Seiyap 四邑 varieties. Rather, 19th century Cantonese has been in close contact with Hokkien, Teochew, and Hakka (which have /iɔŋ/, /iaŋ/ and /ioŋ/ respectively) in the Straits; this has likely slowed further coalescence towards the monophthong /œː/ in Malaysian and Singaporean Cantonese. Nonetheless, the prestige and [normative](https://www.scmp.com/magazines/post-magazine/short-reads/article/2171053/why-cantonese-spoken-malaysia-sounds-different) power of Hong Kong-based media for the Cantonese-speaking world (and indeed for a lot of the Chinese community in Malaysia and Singapore in general - [one example shows](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ralf-Vollmann/publication/341031176_Language_change_and_convergence_in_multilingual_Malaysian_Chinese/links/5ffd00a992851c13fe06aaea/Language-change-and-convergence-in-multilingual-Malaysian-Chinese.pdf?_sg%5B0%5D=started_experiment_milestone&origin=journalDetail&_rtd=e30%3D) how a predominantly Hakka conversation code-switched a few select Cantonese terms) has meant the /œː/ phoneme has now become more common.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed answer, really cleared it up for me!

Comment: Is there either a missing or extraneous palatal in “as with the majority of Middle Chinese /aŋ/ to */jɔŋ/”? Not all /aŋ/ finals became */jɔŋ/, did they? For example, would 湯 (Baxter _thang_ /tʰaŋ/) have become */tʰjɔŋ/ at some stage and then lost the glide again?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have a parenthesis there, but I can certainly make it clearer!

Comment: Oh, I see now – I missed that the brackets stopped after /aŋ/, not after /jɔŋ/!